# CustomCertificateValidator not called when client certificates option is set to "accepted" on IIS

Tags: wcf, authentication, ssl, iis, certificate

I have the following situation:

I am looking for the possibility to authenticate a user at a wcf rest service optionally by username/password or by certificate. I have 2 clients, one is using authentication via username/pw and the other one via certificate.
But the CustomCertificateValidator class like described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/how-to-create-a-service-that-employs-a-custom-certificate-validator is only called when the client certificates option unter SSL in IIS is set to "required", but I need it when set to "accepted" if I want to use the same service. Does anybody know I that doesnt work generally? What I am doing wrong? In my web.config I set the option

Regards, Jimmy

Answer (score 0):

Regarding CustomCertificateValidator, you can download the [wcf demo](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21459) provided by the official document. After downloading, it is the WF_WCF_Samples folder. Go to WCF>Extensibility>Security>X509CertificateValidator. The X509CertificateValidator example shows how to use custom X509CertificateValidator to verify client credentials. The official document also provides [detailed instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/x-509-certificate-validator) for the use of demo.

Comment: My problem is not an implementation problem, it must be a configuation problem, because when I set client certificates to "required" in IIS it works and the custom certificate validator is called, but I need it to "accepted".
The setting <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" /> like in the example will not work, because this tells the service that a client certificate is required